# React click on item to show details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Iam new to React and I'm trying to interact with the swapi API.
I want to get the list of films (movie titles list) and when I click on a title to show the opening_crawl from the json object.
I managed to get the film titles in an array. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Here is my code:

```
class StarWarsApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const title = "Star Wars";
    const subtitle = "Movies";
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={title} />
        <Movies />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Movies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMovies = this.handleMovies.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    };
    this.handleMovies();
  }

  handleMovies() {
    fetch("https://swapi.co/api/films")
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let movies = data.results.map(movie => {
          return <div key={movie.episode_id}>{movie.title}</div>;
        });

        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            movies: movies
          };
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Episodes</h1>
        <div>{this.state.movies}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<StarWarsApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over movies add this in render method:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Episodes</h1>
      {
        this.state.movies.map((movie, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="movie" onClick={this.handleClick} key={i}>{movie.title}
              <div className="opening">{movie.opening_crawl}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Add this method to your Movies component to add active class on click to DIV with "movie" className:

```
handleClick = event => {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Include this css to your project:

```
.movie .opening {
  display: none;
}

.active .opening {
  display: block
}
```

Comment: thank you @Jihlavanka , this sheds some light! I guess I am gonna need webpack to include css in my app??

Comment: @Danae I use create-react-app so I can just write `import "./mystyles.css"` in React component.

Comment: I did also use create-react-app and babel. Babel converts it to "require" and I get a ReferenceError .

Answer (score 1):

After fetching the data, just keep it in your state then use the pieces in your components or JSX. Don't return some JSX from your `handleMovies` method, just do the `setState` part there. Also, I suggest using a life-cycle method (or hooks API maybe if you use a functional component) to trigger the fetching. By the way, don't use class components unless you need a state or life-cycle methods.

After that, you can render your titles in your render method by mapping the movies state. Also, you can have a place for your `opening_crawls` part and render it with a conditional operator. This condition changes with a click. To do that you have an extra state property and keep the movie `id`s there. With the click, you can set the `id` value to `true` and show the crawls.

Here is a simple working example.

```js
const StarWarsApp = () => {
  const title = "Star Wars";
  const subtitle = "Movies";
  return (
    <div>
      <Header title={title} />
      <Movies />
    </div>
  );
}

const Header = ({ title }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
  </div>
);

class Movies extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: [],
    showCrawl: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleMovies();
  }

  handleMovies = () =>
    fetch("https://swapi.co/api/films")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ movies: data.results }));

  handleCrawl = e => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    this.setState(current => ({
      showCrawl: { ...current.showCrawl, [id]: !current.showCrawl[id] }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Episodes</h1>
        <div>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <div
              key={movie.episode_id}
              id={movie.episode_id}
              onClick={this.handleCrawl}
            >
              {movie.title}
              {this.state.showCrawl[movie.episode_id] && (
                <div style={{ border: "1px black solid" }}>
                  {movie.opening_crawl}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<StarWarsApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I am using `id` on the target `div` to get it back from the `event` object. I don't like this method too much but for the sake of clarity, I used this. You can refactor it and create another component may be, then you can pass the `epoisde_id` there and handle the `setState` part. Or you can use a data attribute instead of `id`.